# Yii2 - How to write OAuth Client

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii2, fitbit

I am trying to add FitBit OAuth to my Yii2 app. I have successfully managed to setup other APIs, such as Google and Facebook - but these are using `yii\authclient\clients`. Here I am trying to write my own using `yii\authclient\OAuth2`. Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
namespace app\auth\clients;

class Fitbit extends \yii\authclient\OAuth2{

  public $authUrl = 'https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize';
  public $tokenUrl = 'https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token';
  public $apiBaseUrl = 'https://api.fitbit.com';
  public $scope = 'profile';

  protected function initUserAttributes(){
      return $this->api('/1/user', 'GET');
  }

  protected function defaultName(){
      return 'fitbit';
  }

  protected function defaultTitle(){
      return 'Fitbit';
  }
}
```

Here is the configuration I have:

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
        'google' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Google',
            'clientId' => 'ID',
            'clientSecret' => 'SECRET',
        ],
        'fitbit' => [
            'class' => 'app\auth\clients\Fitbit',
            'clientId' => 'ID',
            'clientSecret' => 'SECRET',
        ],
```

But I am stumped, as this is the error I get:

```
{"errors":[{
    "errorType":"invalid_request",
    "message":"Authorization header required. Visit https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2 for more information on the Fitbit Web API authorization process."
}],
"success":false}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT** My current thinking is something along the lines of:

```
return $this->api('/1/user', 'GET', [], [
  'WWW-Authenticate' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($this->client_id . ':' . $this->client_secret),
]);
```

But this still gives me the same error.

Comment: this might be help you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747765/unable-to-retrieve-json-data-from-fitbit-oauth2-api

Comment: I see how that's similar @vijaynathji but how do I apply that to Yii2?